# Remove extra body generated from Joe schema in swagger

Tags: node.js, swagger, joi

I have two Joi schema like below:

```js
const updateProfile: {
  body: ObjectSchema;
} = {
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    dob: JoiDate.date()
      .format('MM/DD/YYYY')
      .max(new Date())
      .required()
      .default('01/30/2022'),
    genderId: Joi.number().integer().required(),
    weightLbs: Joi.number().required(),
    heightIn: Joi.number().required(),
    ...
  }),
};

const updateUser: {
  body: ObjectSchema;
} = {
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    firstName: Joi.string(),
    lastName: Joi.string(),
    profile: updateProfile
  }),
};

const updateUserSchema = j2s(updateUser.body).swagger;
```

The generated Swagger schema contains an extra `body, is there any way to remove it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `body` from `updateProfile` fixed my problem:

```js
const updateProfile: ObjectSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  dob: JoiDate.date()
    .format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    .raw()
    .max(new Date())
    .required()
    .default('01/30/2022'),
  genderId: Joi.number().integer().required(),
  weightLbs: Joi.number().required(),
  heightIn: Joi.number().required(),
  ...
});
```